# RewriteEngine gives error 500 internal server error for 404 pages - apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

I wanted to replace the .html extensions with just nothing in apache.

Eg. `DNS/coffee.html` to be `DNS/coffee`. I found myself this code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

It does the job I wanted, but it doesn't.

It seems to not like `404.html` for errors. Everytime I open a page that doesn't exist, it doesn't give me the 404 page anymore, but a 500 internal server error message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at EMAIL to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at URL Port 443

I don't know what I am suposed to do, google doesn't give me wise answers, only things like “how to redirect a page to 404.html” or “how to make every link that doesn't go to this DNS reditect to 404 page.”

Here is the code for `.htaccess`.

```
# ------------------Error Pages--------------------
# 404 NOT FOUND
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
# -----------------Rem .html and .htm extensions---
 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your non-HTML rewrite rule is negatively affecting the `/errors/404.html` from ever being loaded.

#### That results in a condition where Apache keeps on trying to load `errors/[something].html` and eventually loops until it dies with a 500 error.

It won’t load the `404.html` page because of the sloppy logic you have here.

If someone goes to `DNS/ddqqweeqewqweewq` — or some other nonsense URL you know doesn’t work — your rules are then telling the server to attempt to load `DNS/ddqqweeqewqweewq.html` and then the resulting error loads `/errors/404/ddqqweeqewqweewq.html`. Which doesn’t exist.

Try adding a url a `RewriteCond` such as `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/errors/` above the `RewriteRule` like this:

```
# ------------------Error Pages--------------------
# 404 NOT FOUND
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
# -----------------Rem .html and .htm extensions---

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/errors/
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: unfortunely...it doesn't work... it's still the same. But tbh it's a good argument.